# Identify processes that are using CLR

Tags: c#, .net

The below code is not listing w3wp process, winforms application process!
How to identify the application pool for w3wp process. Is this approach correct?

**Code**

```
public static List<String> GetCLRManagedProcesses()
    {
        var managedProcesses = new List<Process>();
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            try
            {
                if (process != null && !process.HasExited)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; (i < process.Modules.Count); i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var moduleName = process.Modules[i].ModuleName.ToLowerInvariant();
                            if (FrameworkLibraries().Contains(moduleName))
                            {
                                managedProcesses.Add(process);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // winforms, w3wp, all are entering here
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){ }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
            }
        }

        return managedProcesses
            .Select(x => x.ProcessName)
            .ToList();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<String> FrameworkLibraries()
    {
        return new[] { "mscoree.dll", "mscoreei.dll", "mscorwks.dll" };
    }
```

any help appreciated

Comment: mscoree*.dll is the default CLR host, not used by the kind of process that hosts the CLR itself, like w3wp.exe.  mscorwks.dll is the old name for the CLR, you also need to add mscorsvc.dll to see the serverGC version of the old CLR.  And clr.dll, the new name of the CLR.  Do beware that you'll see them back in thoroughly unmanaged processes, like a browser or Explorer.exe or a CAD program, writing a [ComVisible] .NET assembly is pretty common.